# Convert Columns to row values where column+row is True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that appears as follows:

```
    key f1  f2  f3      f4      f5
0   001 A   B   True    False   False
1   002 C   D   False   True    False
2   003 A   D   False   True    False
3   004 C   B   False   False   True
```

And I'd like to use pandas to convert the above to:

```
    key f1  f2  state
0   001 A   B   f3
1   002 C   D   f4
2   003 A   D   f4
3   004 C   B   f5
```

In short if the row value for the column is True then that column label should become the new value of a column called state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A colleague of mine gave me this, which appears to work exactly as desired.

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['key', 'f1', 'f2'],
       var_name = 'state')
      .query('value')
      .drop('value', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    key f1  f2  state
0   001 A   B   f3
5   002 C   D   f4
6   003 A   D   f4
11  004 C   B   f5
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`Dataframe.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
t = df.loc[:,'f3':]
df['state'] = t.dot(t.columns)
```

---

```
print(df.drop(t.columns, axis=1))

   key f1 f2 state
0    1  A  B    f3
1    2  C  D    f4
2    3  A  D    f4
3    4  C  B    f5
```

---

Or we could also use `idxmax`:

```
df['state'] = t.idxmax(1)
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of feedback to use pd.melt; however, the the closest of I have gotten to getting that to work is 
df.melt(id_vars['key', 'f1', 'f2'], value_name='state'
This approach repeats all the rows, creates a new column variable and essentially puts the True|False under state.  Not what I'm looking for though I could drop rows with False.